# Profile creation workflow message, where is it located?

Tags: profile, system-workflow-messages

I would like to modify format and content of profile creation notification email message. Which template is it?

Answer (score 1):

**Administer -> CiviMail -> Message Templates -> System Workflow Messages tab -> Profiles - Admin Notification**

Looks like it, although personally I haven't tried this before.

Answer (score 1):

Administer -> Communications -> Message Templates -> system Workflow Messages

This is straight forward look for the Workflow title and edit your message template - will work